# Converting a Collection of Base Object to Collection of Child Object

Tags: c#, .net

I have class which implements from an interface IX;

```
interface IX
{  
    Type t;
    int id;
}
class X : IX
{   
    public string x;   
    public string y;   
    public string z;
}
```

I get a Collection of IX[]. I want write a generic code which I can type cast to the required object like X to a collection of X[].

Comment: Your code was badly formatted to start with and is still invalid as you can't declare fields in an interface. Please provide a *complete* example. Additionally, please explain whether you actually need arrays (as per your example) or other collection types as well or instead.

Comment: those fields are basically properties. I am getting a array of type  interface. To get an Object X I need to cast every item in the array. So i need a generic way of doing it.

Comment: If they're meant to be properties, you should *show* them as properties... and if your question is specific to arrays, you should *say* it's specific to arrays rather than just collections. Next, what's creating the array? Is it *actually* an `X[]` but you're being presented it as an `IX[]`? Do you even know that every element is an `X` reference? What's wrong with just casting? There's a *lot* of context missing here - please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: If you get an array of interface, it's usually a bad idea to typecast it back to the concrete implementation. The goal of using interfaces is specifically to hide the concrete implementation of the objects you're using, so that they can be changed easily. The question would be "why" do you want to get the concrete type instead of just working with the interface?

Comment: I am a UI developer and I am getting a collection of an Array. there is no other form I can get this data. this collection needs to be bound to a UI Control lets say a Grid.  Lets say a I bound this array to the datasource of the Grid at that time I am able to get all the properties of the Class X and Its Interface IX. The reason I need to Type cast is today its Class X, tomorow it might be Class Y implementing the same Intergace IX.

Comment: @user1862425 isn't that exactly why you don't want to cast it? shouldn't you be using the interface properties instead of casting it at all? If it changes to class Y and class Y doesn't have any relation to class X beyond IX the code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for it.

```
IX[] IXes;
// populating IXes here...
X[] Xes;
Xes = IXes.Cast<X>().ToArray();
```

Generic method for this process will look like

```
static TClass[] Cast<TInterface, TClass>(TInterface[] a) where TClass : TInterface
{
    return a.Cast<TClass>().ToArray();
}
```